# Add a link in OverLeaf

Tags: urls, links

I need to refer to a link in my project, I am using `\url{}` as following:

```
\url{\\192.123.123.456\d$\bla3_Delivery\asdasd3.3\asdasd\asdasdas}
```

But I get something weird as you can see in the attached picture. I need the link to be displayed literally as it is.
[image: the displayed link]

When i hover on the error it shows this:
[image]

Minimal non-working example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\url{\\192.123.123.456\d$\bla3_Delivery\asdasd3.3\asdasd\asdasdas}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Did you add the necessary package? Please, read about [Minimum Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/140133)s. You will have a better chance of get help from people here when you post a minimal, but complete, working example.

Comment: Are you sure that these are \ in your url and not `/` ? This looks fishy....

Comment: With `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\url{///192.123.123.456/d$/bla3_Delivery/asdasd3.3/asdasd/asdasdas}
\end{document}` it would work perfectly fine...

Comment: Yes i have \documentclass{article} \usepackage{hyperref} and it is \.

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10444621/2777074

Comment: It is the \  that causes the problem as you pointed  @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz 
Thank you very much!

Comment: If I load `url` package instead of `hyperref`, your MWE works on my machine. If I load `hyperref`, those single backslashes need to be escaped meaning I need two `\\` in place of `\`. So to typeset your ulr with `hyperref`, I would need this:   `\url{\\\\192.123.123.456\\d$\\bla3_Delivery\\asdasd3.3\\asdasd\\asdasdas}`. Whether it is on purpose with `url` I cannot tell. I would stick with `hyperref`, though.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question has been solved in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The slashes in your url should be `/` instead of `\` .

For details about backslahes in the url system, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10444621/2777074 , but chances are that whenever you see a backslash, it shouldn't be a backslash.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\begin{document} 
\url{///192.123.123.456/d$/bla3_Delivery/asdasd3.3/asdasd/asdasdas} 
\end{document}
```